# Create modal window based on the domain of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, css, fancybox

Does anybody know if it is possible to create a modal window using fancybox or something else based on the domain of a link on a page? I'm displaying the output of a query on a page and I don't have the ability to add CSS class information to the output. Therefore, I'm wondering if it is possible for jQuery to figure it out on the page load an insert a class. Here is the output HTMl I'm working with.

[More Info](http://learning.westerncpe.com/local/api/html.php?checkkey=s7KHngo3PBh28gkS9MY2&id=362&field=summary)

Link to page: http://goo.gl/pA3W7Y

I was thinking maybe the jQuery could match on the term "More Info". If that term were to appear on the page it would match against that. I'm really scratching my head here. Any insight would be appreciated. Cheers.

Steve.

Comment: So the matching should be done based on the domain, or based on stuff in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this easily with regex or indexOf.

indexOf example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').each(function(x) {
        var link = $(this).attr('href'); //get href from <a>
        var s = "learning.westerncpe.com/local/api/html.php";
        if (link.indexOf(s) !== -1) {
            $(this).addClass('fancybox');
        }
    });
});

$('.fancybox').click(function (e) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        'autowidth': 'true',
        'width': 900,
        'height': 700,
        'type': 'iframe'
    });
});
```

Edit: realized that you'd be doing this off of a link on the page, so added jQuery wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I understand where you're coming from, but I'm having trouble implementing it. My links are still executing and aren't rendering in a modal. To be clear, there are going to be 25-50 links on a page this would apply to. I set up a dev site to try to implement this. -- http://goo.gl/eynZEY. Here is what the production site would look like http://goo.gl/4r9LSU. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. THANK YOU!!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/7tKsj/ Here is a working fiddle. In your examples there you had the selector as `$('fancybox fancybox.iframe')`. The way jQuery works is that selector field has to match the class, id, or element of your DOM. You'll see in the jsFiddle that I had to first add the fancybox class to your <a> links, and then updated the selector to be simply `'.fancybox'`

Comment: Thanks for the code! Sorry, I should have been more clear. I do not have the ability to declare a class in my links. The links are getting outputted directly from a query which I don't have the ability to modify. The output HTML is exactly "http://learning.westerncpe.com/local/api/html.php?checkkey=s7KHngo3PBh28gkS9MY2&id=362&field=summary". Unfortunately, I can't put anything on there. So I'm thinking is there a way that jQuery could add it when the page loads. Any insight would be appreciated. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: Ahh, now I understand. See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/7tKsj/1/

Comment: This is definitely a step in the right direction! However, this is responding for all links on the page, not just for the ones specified in the script. The actual page isn't loading in the Modal, but the modal is still coming up. Ideally, I just want the modal to occur for the specified link and everything else on the page is unaffected. Any idea on how to make this just respond to the one we specified? THANK YOU! Beers are on me if you're anywhere near Los Angeles. Thanks. Steve.

Comment: Ah! You're right. It wasn't going to work the other way. This isn't the most optimized, but try this: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/7tKsj/4/

You're looping through all <a> elements on document load, and only adding the fancybox class if it matches the right URL.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and support! You're the best!! Thank you! Thank you!!

Comment: yw @SteveYoss! Good luck